# Dynamic payload in Python request

Tags: python, request, payload

I have a request in Python and want to make it dynamic. It is about the payload query, how can I add a variable in my payload?
I've tried to use .format but this doesn't work.

```
url = "https://graphql.bitquery.io"
payload = "{\"query\":\"{\\r\\n  ethereum(network: bsc) {\\r\\n    dexTrades(\\r\\n      options: {limit: 100, desc: \\\"tradeAmount\\\"}\\r\\n      date: {after: \\\"2021-04-30\\\"}\\r\\n      buyCurrency: {in: \\\"0xe7a39e210f067caad7992e6866beceb95b4394f7\\\"}\\r\\n    ) {\\r\\n      transaction {\\r\\n        hash\\r\\n      }\\r\\n      date {\\r\\n        date\\r\\n      }\\r\\n      buyAmount\\r\\n      buyAmountInUsd: buyAmount(in: USD)\\r\\n      buyCurrency {\\r\\n        symbol\\r\\n        address\\r\\n        tokenId\\r\\n        tokenType\\r\\n        decimals\\r\\n        name\\r\\n      }\\r\\n      sellAmount\\r\\n      sellCurrency {\\r\\n        symbol\\r\\n        address\\r\\n      }\\r\\n      sellAmountInUsd: sellAmount(in: USD)\\r\\n      tradeAmount(in: USD)\\r\\n      smartContract {\\r\\n        address {\\r\\n          address\\r\\n          annotation\\r\\n        }\\r\\n        protocolType\\r\\n      }\\r\\n    }\\r\\n  }\\r\\n}\\r\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
headers = {
    'X-API-KEY': '',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if I am understanding this correctly, the graphql api is taking a json formatted string and you want to modify the query part of the json. If you split up the two and provide `%s` formatting for the desired variables you wish to change in the payload, it should work.

I have used `date` and `desc` as examples but any other variables you wish to change this method can also be used.

```py
import json
import requests

date = '2021-04-30'
desc = 'tradeAmount'
query = """

{
  ethereum(network: bsc) {
    dexTrades(
      options: { limit: 100, desc: "%s" }
      date: { after: "%s" }
      buyCurrency: { in: "0xe7a39e210f067caad7992e6866beceb95b4394f7" }
    ) {
      transaction {
        hash
      }
      date {
        date
      }
      buyAmount
      buyAmountInUsd: buyAmount(in: USD)
      buyCurrency {
        symbol
        address
        tokenId
        tokenType
        decimals
        name
      }
      sellAmount
      sellCurrency {
        symbol
        address
      }
      sellAmountInUsd: sellAmount(in: USD)
      tradeAmount(in: USD)
      smartContract {
        address {
          address
          annotation
        }
        protocolType
      }
    }
  }
}


""" % (desc, date)

d = {'query': query, 'variables': {}}
payload = json.dumps(d)

url = "https://graphql.bitquery.io"
headers = {
    'X-API-KEY': '',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```